# Typescript 4.8: how to extends Node stream.Writable

Tags: node.js, typescript, stream

I am trying to create a simple class implementing [Node stream.Writable](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/stream.html#class-streamwritable) but it seems I can't get the syntax right, the compiler is always complaining:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. Any hint?

`node`: `16.17.0`
`@types/node`: `16.11.64`
`typescript`: `4.8.3`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Show code snippets through pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the `_write` method *outside* of the constructor.

```
class MyWritable extends Writable {
  constructor() {
    super({ objectMode: true });
  }
  
  // moved outside the constructor function.
  _write(chunk: any, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: () => void) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Which works without errors. [See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgdSsGBDARgGwKYA0KamueA8mDMBAHYDOcAvnHAGZQQhwDk9MUPBhA8A3AChxAYxwZ6jALIBPVOmz44eAB4w8tACaNVpDQnGspdflACuUmNAAUASkTnWcejbB4ojpBBYAFZ49goQ+ngAXHACNnjMzhKsTJKsAPoA7iR4jlIAFja0ANYxGLRKRHqW+sC0AOYxAEI2bGy+AKK0NXX1RFIYODhYGFKlcC5wALwAfHAAbhDA+q5mHnAA9BsAdLvuqUxAA)

Comment: I am sorry, my bad :(